# Strange math calculations in php

Tags: php, math

I am trying to make this calculation in php but is giving me wrong result. I think that is right.

And if i do 5000.00 - 100.10 it works, but i want the 5,000.00 to work too.

This is my code:

To create the 5,000.00 i have used number_format(5000, 2).
Aswell to the 100.10

```
    $total = $value1 - $value2;

    echo $total;  
?>
```

$total = -95.00

I am trying to make this calculation in php but is giving me wrong result. I think that is right.

And if i do 5000.00 - 100.10 it works, but i want the 5,000.00 to work too.

Please Help...

Comment: I am totally lost as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you are trying to use the result of `number_format` as a float value. It's a string. Not all strings can be converted back to a float (comas for example will break conversion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do arithmetic on number, you can't have the thousands separator (`,`). What's happening is `5,000.00` is being read as `5` (it stops interpreting it as a number as soon as it hits the comma) and then you're getting `5 - 100.10` which is `-95.10` (I'm thinking you left off the `.10` in your example.

You'll need to convert first:

```
$value1 = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $original_value1))
$value2 = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $original_value2))
```

I'm assuming here that you have them as strings originally. These remove the comma separator.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're confusing rendering in the UI with calculations.

It's perfectly reasonable for a user to see currencies rendered according to their locale rules (e.g. a String "$1,000.00" in USA), but the calculations in the back need to done on a floating point number (e.g. 1000.0).

So you have to be able to convert back and forth between them.  You can't make arithmetic operations work on a String.  Better to parse the String to a float, do the operations, then convert that back to String for rendering.